# macOS partition deleted cannot boot into recovery mode or do anything please help only windows partition works

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac, partitioning, recovery

I installed macOS 12.0 beta and since then it was stuck on a bootloop, then i tried to get to recovery mode, safe boot, reset SMC/NVRAM. And since I did not make a time machine backup I couldn't go back to Big Sur. I can only access my windows bootcamp partition. I tried various ways to get to recovery mode like through internet recovery. I have a T2 chip so I cannot use a USB bootable drive without disabling the security from recovery.

I am going to apple genius bar in a week to see if they can do anything, but I have some pretty important files on my mac partition. When i go to the option/alt menu on startup I only see my windows disk NO macintosh HD. I think the partition got deleted and I cannot recover the files please please please HELP

Comment: Wait until you see Apple. The T2 will prevent you doing anything else before then. Golden Rule: never run beta software on a mission-critical machine without a known-good & tested recovery plan.